# I am trying to create an add function for my widgets but it is not working as intended

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add widgets to my app I have created an array to represent the layout and an array of component choices to choose from. Unfortunately when I click add widget it is not allowing me to select which one I want. Instead it results to the default Data Table widget which I have set as the state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Swappable from './components/SwappableComponent'
import './App.css';
import DataTable from './components/tableWidget';
import CheckboxList from './components/CheckboxList';
import AddWidgetDialog from './components/AddWidgetDialog';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { Table } from '@material-ui/core';



const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  }
});

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={
        selectedWidgetId: "Data Table",
        widgetOptions:[{name:"Data Table", comp:<DataTable/>},{name:"List", comp:<CheckboxList/>}],

        widgets:[ //array for layout 
          {id:1, content: <DataTable/>},
          {id:2, content: <CheckboxList/>},
          {id:3, content: ""},
          {id:4, content: ""}
        ],
        isModalOpen: false
      }

    }
    handleWidgetSelection=(id) => {
      this.setState({selectedWidgetId: id})
    }
    deleteEvent=(index)=>{
        const copyWidgets=Object.assign([],this.state.widgets);
        let widget=this.state.widgets[index];
        widget.content="";
        copyWidgets[index]=widget;
        this.setState({
            widgets:copyWidgets
        })
    }
    addEvent=(index)=>{
        this.setState({isModalOpen: true}) 
        const copyWidgets=Object.assign([],this.state.widgets); 
        let widget=this.state.widgets[index]; 
        console.log("state::", JSON.stringify(this.state))
        widget.content=this.state.widgetOptions.find(w => w.name === this.state.selectedWidgetId).comp; 
        copyWidgets[index]=widget; 
        this.setState({ 
            widgets:copyWidgets 
        }) 
    }

    onRequestClose = () => {
        this.setState({
          isModalOpen: false,
        });
      }
    render() {
      const { classes } = this.props;

      return (

      <div className={classes.root}>
      <AddWidgetDialog handleWidgetSelection={this.handleWidgetSelection} widgets={this.state.widgetOptions} isModalOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} onRequestClose={this.onRequestClose} />
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
            {
                this.state.widgets.map((widget,index)=>{
                    return(
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                            <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id={widget.id} content={widget.content} delete={this.deleteEvent.bind(this,index)} add={this.addEvent.bind(this,index)}/></Paper>
                         </Grid>
                    )
                })
            }
        </Grid>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }

  App.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the first setState in addEvent and add the isModalOpen: true property to the second setState?

Comment: No it behaves the same way, sadly.

Comment: What about if you try `let widget = Object.assign({}, this.state.widgets[index]);`

Comment: I am still getting the same error